# How do I convert an epoch timestamp to a human readable format on the cli?

Tags: command-line, shell, date

How do I convert an epoch timestamp to a human readable format on the cli? I think there's a way to do it with date but the syntax eludes me (other ways welcome).

Answer (score 430, accepted):

On *BSD:

```
date -r 1234567890
```

On Linux (specifically, with GNU coreutils ≥5.3):

```
date -d @1234567890
```

With older versions of GNU date, you can calculate the relative difference to the UTC epoch:

```
date -d '1970-01-01 UTC + 1234567890 seconds'
```

If you need portability, you're out of luck. The only time you can format with a POSIX shell command (without doing the calculation yourself) line is the current time. In practice, Perl is often available:

```
perl -le 'print scalar localtime $ARGV[0]' 1234567890
```

Comment: +1 for the comment about the lack of portability (why doesn't the POSIX spec include a way to do this?  grr)

Comment: What does the `@` mean in `date -d @1234567890`? `man date` made no reference to that...

Comment: @ChrisMarkle GNU man pages are often woefully incomplete. “The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.” To wit: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch

Comment: The `info date` is quite complete. The entry at `28.9 Seconds since the Epoch` explains in detail about the @timestamp.

Comment: In Linux in a pipe: date +'%s' | xargs -I n date -d @n

Comment: To display the date in UTC, add the `-u` option.

Comment: `date -r 1234567890` works on macOS's fork of BSD FWIW

Comment: It outputs the date-time in the system timezone. What do I need to do in order to get the date-time always in UTC?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash `env TZ=UTC date …`

Answer (score 39):

If your epoch time is in milliseconds instead of seconds, either put a dot before last three digits (as hinted in comments by user79743), or remove the last three digits before passing it to `date -d`:

Entered directly, this gives incorrect result :

```
$ date -d @1455086371603
Tue Nov  7 02:46:43 PST 48079     #Incorrect
```

Put a dot before last three digits:

```
$ date -d @1455086371.603
Tue Feb  9 22:39:32 PST 2016     #Correct
```

Or, remove the last three digits:

```
$ date -d @1455086371
Tue Feb  9 22:39:31 PST 2016      #Correct after removing the last three digits. You may remove and round off the last digit too.
```

Comment: What utility prints included milliseconds (without a dot) ?

Comment: I have seen that WebLogic Application server mostly returns data time values with milliseconds and no dots when using scripting tool. 
e.g., lastSuccessfulConnectionUse=1455086371603

Comment: I see. This page confirms [Raw Time Value The timestamp in milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/logging/logging_services.html). Thanks.

Comment: Atlassian tools log their timestamps as epoch time with milliseconds.

Comment: This doesn't work on HP-UX.

Answer (score 31):

`date -d @1190000000` Replace 1190000000 with your epoch

Comment: Assuming GNU date, that is.

Comment: This doesn't work on HP-UX.

Answer (score 20):

Custom format with GNU `date`:

```
date -d @1234567890 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Or with GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 1234567890); }'
```

Linked SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249827/convert-from-unixtime-at-command-line

Comment: Only works for GNU date and GNU awk. Neither awk nor nawk support strftime.

Answer (score 20):

With `bash-4.2` or above:

```
$ printf '%(%FT%T%z)T\n' 1234567890
2009-02-13T23:31:30+0000
```

(where `%FT%T%z` is the `strftime()`-type format, here using standard unambiguous format which includes the UTC offset (`%z`))

That syntax is inspired from `ksh93`.

In `ksh93` however, the argument is taken as a date expression where various and hardly documented formats are supported.

For a Unix epoch time, the syntax in `ksh93` is:

```
printf '%(%FT%T%z)T\n' '#1234567890'
```

`ksh93` however seems to use its own algorithm for the timezone and can get it wrong. For instance, in mainland Britain, it was summer time all year in 1970, but:

```
$ TZ=Europe/London bash -c 'printf "%(%c)T\n" 0'
Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 BST
$ TZ=Europe/London ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%c)T\n" "#0"'
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
```

ksh93 (and [zsh's `strftime` builtin](/a/219551)) support subsecond, not bash yet:

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%(%FT%T.%6N%z)T\n" 1234567890.123456789'
2009-02-13T23:31:30.123456-0000
$ zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime %FT%T.%6.%z 1234567890 123456780'
2009-02-13T23:31:30.123457+0000
```

Comment: This actually works on HP-UX. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
$ echo 1190000000 | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e' 
Sun Sep 16 20:33:20 2007
```

This can come in handy for those applications which use epoch time in the logfiles:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/nagios/nagios.log | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'
[Thu May 13 10:15:46 2010] EXTERNAL COMMAND: PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;HOSTA;check_raid;0;check_raid.pl: OK (Unit 0 on Controller 0 is OK)
```

Answer (score 10):

The two I frequently use are:

```
$ perl -leprint\ scalar\ localtime\ 1234567890
Sat Feb 14 00:31:30 2009
```

and

```
$ tclsh
% clock format 1234567890
Sa Feb 14 00:31:30 CET 2009
```

Comment: Love this `tclsh` suggestion, that seems much easier to remember than most of the incantations in this thread

Comment: The perl one worked for me with timestamp formated like `1.679703228911E9`

Answer (score 9):

With `zsh` you could use the [`strftime`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fdatetime-Module) builtin:

```
strftime format epochtime

      Output the date denoted by epochtime in the format specified.
```

e.g.

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime '%A, %d %b %Y' 1234567890
```

```
Friday, 13 Feb 2009
```

---

There's also `dateconv` from [`dateutils`](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/):

```
dateconv -i '%s' -f '%A, %d %b %Y' 1234567890
```

```
Friday, 13 Feb 2009
```

keep in mind `dateutils` tools default to `UTC` (add `-z your/timezone` if needed).

Comment: It doesn't look like `dateutils` is available on HP-UX.

Comment: On Debian, the `dateutils` package has the `dateutils.dconv` binary instead of `dateconv`.  I'm assuming it's the same thing, but renamed.

Answer (score 1):

In [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/overview):

```
(([System.DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliSeconds($unixtime)).DateTime).ToString("s")
```

Comment: This technique is using Microsoft .NET. It doesn't seem OP is looking for an MS solution.

Comment: Reviewers: PowerShell is available on Linux ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt, but does `PowerShell` run on HP-UX? Seeming no:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8cx8dp/powershell_6_core_and_rhel_and_hpux/ . 

And this is `unix.`

Comment: @saulius2 by that reasoning, most of the content of Unix.SE is invalid, because it’s possible to find a Unix system where it isn’t applicable. This is Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: @StephenKitt, maybe it's so, I made no research about quality of the questions. But just by looking at the right side of this page I see three of them which are asking about the specific OS:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86507/convert-timestamp-to-formatted-time-osx

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96189/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-format-on-aix

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434844/convert-a-date-to-unix-timestamp-on-openbsd

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a little C program for printing the datetime in the format  that can be directly parsed by shell

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc==1) { 
        return 1;
    }

    struct tm input_tm;
    char * formatStr  = "YEAR=%Y\nMON=%m\nDAY=%d\nHOUR=%H\nMIN=%M\nSEC=%S";
    size_t formatSize = strlen(formatStr) + 2;
    char * output     = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*formatSize);

    strptime(argv[1],"%s",&input_tm);
    strftime(output, formatSize, formatStr, &input_tm);

    printf("%s\n",output);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

usage:

```
#compile
clang -o epoch2datetime main.c

#invoke
eval `./epoch2datetime 1450196411`
echo $YEAR $MON $DAY $HOUR $MIN $SEC
#output
#2015 12 16 00 20 11
```

Comment: Doesn't work on HP-UX:

`./a.out 1599099168`
`YEAR=1901`
`MON=03`
`DAY=00`
`HOUR=2130568304`
`MIN=`

Comment: @saulius2 ... what? I completely believe you, but the situation is kind of crazy. HP-UX can't correctly handle `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `string.h`, and `time.h` in Standard (ANSI/ISO) C !?!?!? `. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .` What the `for i in {1..4}; do ascii_base10_val=$(echo "33+$(shuf -i 0-14 -n 1)" | bc -l); ascii_hex_val=$(echo "obase=16; ${ascii_base10_val}" | bc); printf "\x${ascii_hex_val}"; done; echo` has HP-UX done! `. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .` (The code will give a [cartoon representation of a cuss word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grawlix), by the way.)

Comment: Well, I didn't investigate at the time, and now I have lost access to these HP-UX boxes, so I cannot investigate at the moment too.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be a real solution without a little node.js:

```
epoch2date(){
    node -p "new Date($1)"
}
```

add that to `~/.bash_aliases` and make sure its sourced in `~/.bashrc` with `. ~/.bash_aliases`

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

To get node on your system goto http://nvm.sh and run the curl command. It'll install node version manager (nvm) which allows you to switch versions of node.

Just type `nvm ls-remote` and pick a version to `nvm install <version>`.

Comment: Does `node.js` run on HP-UX? Seemingly no:
https://github.com/playnodeconf/ama/issues/10#issuecomment-211250773

Answer (score 0):

If UTC is your preference (for the sample epoch timestamp 1666666666),

```
$ # long options; Linux
$ date --date=@1666666666 --utc
Tue 14 Nov 22:13:20 UTC 2023

$ # short options; Linux
$ date -d @1666666666 -u
Tue 14 Nov 22:13:20 UTC 2023
```