# convert timestamp to formatted time OSX

Tags: osx, date, bsd

I had this working on Ubuntu but I'm now trying to run the script on OSX but it seems that the formatting of date is different.

Originally I had:

`date -d "$MODDATE" +%F" "%H":"%M`

where `$MODDATE` is a unix timestamp generated with stat

However the above date function doesn't work the same way on BSD versions. How can I convert the timestamp to the date in the following format:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM ?

Comment: In what format is `$MODDATE`? There are plenty of different `stat` commands that can produce a variety of formats. If you can get it in number of seconds from the epoch, do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
$ date -jf "<input format>" "<input value>" +"<output format>"
```

For example:

```
$ date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "2011-11-13 08:11:02" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
2013-08-13 09:11
```

#### References

- [How to convert a date string to the current time zone on the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/356898/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-the-current-time-zone-on-the-command-line)
- [date man page (osx)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/date.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

To generate a timestamp: `date +%s`.

And how to convert that timestamp?

### macOS

Use the following:

```
date -jf "%s" "<timestamp value>" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

And with `1638449406` as timestamp:

```
date -jf "%s" "1638449406" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

it will print:

```
2021-12-02 13:50
```

#### Unix:

Use the following:

```
date -ud @<timestamp value> +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Again, with `1638449406` as timestamp:

```
date -ud @1638449406 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

it will print:

```
2021-12-02 13:50
```

Comment: `date -ud @1638449406 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` is the GNU syntax, not Unix syntax and would give you the UTC time, not local time for that Unix epoch time.