# Convert Unix timestamp into human-readable format on AIX

Tags: ksh, date, aix, timestamps

I need to convert unix timestamp (number of seconds since 1970, e.g. 1381260225 is Tue Oct  8 19:23:45 GMT 2013) into a standard human-readable format.

I could get some answers by googling but those were not a suitable solution for me because I don't use Linux, I use an [AIX 6.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp) machine with ksh88. **AIX does not have GNU utilities.**

Comment: How amenable are you to a C-program?

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: The AIX machine which I use is not having C compiler.

Comment: You say you don't have the GNU utilities, what does `which perl` return on the server?  Also, give that relies on your path and we don't know what that is, how about `ls -l /usr/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 3):

If you were on Linux, you could simply use:

```
date -d @1381260225
```

Or you could use gawk:

```
echo "1381260225" | gawk '{print strftime("%c",$1)}'
```

Or Python:

```
python -c "import datetime; print  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1381865497)"
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -e 'print(scalar(localtime(1381865497)), "\n";'
```

However none of these solutions are available on a stock AIX installation.
All of these tools (GNU coreutils, GNU awk, Perl, Python) are available as separate packages as part of the [AIX toolbox for Linux applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/).

Comment: `date -d` is a GNU-ism.  The equivalent for OpenBSD would be `date -r 1381260225`.  And I'm not even sure that is standard, because Solaris doesn't even have an equivalent of `-d` or `-r`.  Solaris only seems to be able to set or display the current time.

Comment: @kurtm AIX date does not seem to have `-r` either, see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/date.htm). I think RahulPatil's `awk` solution will be the most portable.

Comment: @terdon I concur that the awk solution is probably the most portable.  I figured AIX wouldn't support it either, but don't have any AIX machines I can check.

Comment: @kurtm You can look up [AIX man pages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp) online. None of these methods work on AIX, not even the awk method as [awk](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/awk.htm) doesn't have `strftime` (it's a GNU extension).

Comment: @Gilles Neat, thank you.  I've bookmarked that for future reference.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have either Python or perl modules installed to use them.

@kurtm&Gilles: is there any work around to achieve this.

Comment: For info: AIX comes with perl, I'm pretty sure it's installed by default. You don't need to use the AIX toolbox for Linux to install it, it's in the base image.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably fall back to Perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime($ARGV[0])), "\n"' 1381260225
```

```
2013-10-08 15:23:45
```

Comment: +1 but if I'm not mistaken, AIX does not have Perl by default and I don't know whether `POSIX::strftime` will be installed even if it does. Can these be installed without root access on AIX?

Comment: @terdon is python default install in AIX ?

Comment: @RahulPatil I doubt it (but don't really know). However, both perl and python can be downloaded from [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html).

Comment: @RahulPatil If something doesn't have perl by default, it's not likely to have python by default.

Comment: @RahulPatil&tredon: The machine I use does not have either Perl or Python at the same time I do not have admin access to the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
# echo 1381260225 | python -c 'import sys; import time; print time.ctime( float( sys.stdin.read() ) )'
Wed Oct  9 02:23:45 2013
```

Comment: A Python answer has already been given. AIX does not have Python installed by default.

Comment: My one is better. Compare number of letters.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more perlish:

```
echo 1397028688|perl -l12ne 'print scalar localtime $_'
Wed Apr  9 09:31:28 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

AIX has ksh93, so:

- local time (here mainland Britain):

  ```
  $ ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %T %z)T\n" "#$1"' ksh93 1381260225
  2013-10-08 20:23:45 +0100
  ```
- GMT/UTC

  ```
  $ TZ=GMT0 ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %T %Z)T\n" "#$1"' ksh93 1381260225
  2013-10-08 19:23:45 GMT
  ```

Answer (score -3):

what about something like this ??

```
echo "`date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S"`"
```

Comment: You meant `echo "$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")"` but it only outputs the Unix timestamp of the current date. The question was about converting a *specified* Unix timestamp to a *human-readable* date string.

Comment: You're using backticks so the double quotes don't nest. Consider using the more modern style `$( ... )` instead.