# How can I convert timestamps in a column to a date?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a file containing this:

```
1415602803,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
1415602807,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
1415602811,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
1415602815,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,user3,192.168.123.55,10.146.32.99,55750,22
```

I want to convert the timestamp to a date in this format:

```
2014-11-10 02:00:03,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
2014-11-10 02:00:07,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
2014-11-10 02:00:11,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
2014-11-10 02:00:15,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,user3,192.168.123.55,10.146.32.99,55750,22
```

How can I do that?

I know this works: `perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'` (from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2992/38128)) but the output format is `Mon Nov 10 02:00:03 2014`.

I know this command can convert timestamps into my desired output: `date -d@1415602803 +"%F %H:%M:%S"`, but I couldn't make it work with `awk` using `system("cmd")` because of all the quotations and whatnot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this perhaps

```
perl -pe 'use POSIX qw(strftime); s/^(\d+)/strftime "%F %H:%M:%S", localtime($1)/e'
```

Answer (score 26):

Found something here: [Stackoverflow - Convert from unixtime at command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249936/2767757).

Came up with this:

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1); print $0}' file
```

- `-F","` to use a field separator of `,`,
- `OFS=",";` so that the output fields are also separated by a `,`,
- `$1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1);` to change the value of the first field `$1` into the specified format, and
- `print $0;` to print the whole line.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 0) }'` gives `awk: line 2: function strftime never defined` here. Please clarify that NOT EVERY AWK has `strftime()`! For a solution running in most (all?) AWKs, please use the external `date` command to stay portable.

Comment: @yeti, there are a few `date` implementations that can convert dates between formats as an extension, but how it's done varies completely between the implementations. For instance, the solution given by Costas uses a syntax specific to GNU `date`. If you want portability, use `perl`.

Answer (score 7):

If you like `awk` you can use external command `date` with any date formats

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{("date +%F\ %T -d @"$1)|getline $1}1'
```

Comment: +1 for NOT using `strftime()`!

Comment: Note that using an external command will incur a severe performance hit, especially noticeable if many thousands of rows are being processed

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/`date -d @\1`/; s/$/"/' | bash
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked a question 9 months ago that was marked a duplicate of this one. I only just now saw a request to post the answer that worked for me on this question. Here is a link to that question and answer.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304009/172916