Combine in Command history all Users on root
i try at the moment to combine all users history in root, that should increase the security.
we need to see what the last user`s executed or which file the user changed.
I tried a lot; Symlinks; configure the bashrc file but nothing works.
had anywhere and idea for this?
OS:Linux CLI (Command Line Interface) No Desktop OS
The output at the moment via history-command:
[root] 153  16.10.2024 13:49:55 reboot
[root] 154  16.10.2024 13:51:04 history

What i need for an output via history-command
[root] 153  16.10.2024 13:50:55 reboot
[root] 154  16.10.2024 13:52:04 history
[user1] 155  16.10.2024 13:53:55 reboot
[user1] 156  16.10.2024 13:54:04 history
[user2] 157  16.10.2024 13:55:55 rm file.txt
[dev2] 158 16.10.2024 13:56:04 nano /var/log/server.log

I need to combine that in the normal root bashrc
how i said what i tried is a Symlink and to configure the bashrc but nothing give me a correct output. I cannot manage to combine the users of the System
Symlink
[root] 50  16.10.2024 12:52:41 ln -s /home/user1/.bash_history /root/.bash_history


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Recording user's history is of no use for security, because it is trivially simple to bypass the history process. For example, I can run view without a filename, and issue any command I choose as a child of vi with the vi command : ! anything I want. By extension, I can save any script I choose to type from that vi into /tmp, execute it with : ! bash /tmp/x, then rm it. There will be no trace except a bare view command in my history. Several other commands be exploited in similar ways.

Hey @Paul_Pedant thank you for your message. Hmm Okay. I know that the Command History is not tracking all Commands especially when you use interactive Shell or something. For us is it important so see some commands that a user executed. That is for us easier to understand which file was edited or which service was restarted from which user, that we also can we fix a problem fast. We need to trust in this Situtation our employees. Have you an Idea to make this happen? I tried am symlink and to configure the bashrc file.
And did you have another Idea maybe a Service to check it like history?

Please [edit] your question and include this context. Also describe what you tried and why it didn't work for you. What operating system is this for? Should it include GUI commands? What is a command, anyway? If I right click on something, is that a command? Why do you need anything more than the normal shell history, if you don't need GUI clicks?

You are looking for an auditing solution, look into auditd and consorts

@AyGuddedachach  On the contrary, history is only recorded for commands within interactive shells. I read the Bash manual carefully for 5 minutes, and I now know seven new ways to hide the history, and cannot think how to prevent any of them. (Mess with HISTCONTROL, HISTIGNORE, HISTSIZE, HISTFILE, HISTFILESIZE, make the history file permissions read-only, or run an ssh session on the local machine.) History is provided to make it convenient for the user to repeat and modify commands: it is useless for auditing users.

@Paul_Pedant: How does running an ssh session on the local machine hide/subvert command history?

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'  IIRC, the ssh client provides its own CLI -- the shell that ran ssh does not see the commands that you issue interactively. The shell that sshd runs is not interactive, so it records no history. If you inspect the history file for audit purposes, you can see ssh itself was run, but not the detail of what was executed within the session.

@Panki hey i tried the auditd service but i figure out that the timestamp format absolutely trash is :-D. Otherwise it works well.
Do you have an Idea to convert the timestamp format from epoch to humanreadable time format?

@AyGuddedachach https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/ (many roads lead to Rome)
